# Disable cache decorator for testing for dogpile.cache

Tags: python, caching, pylons, beaker, dogpile.cache

I recently switched from beaker to dogpile.cache. It works very well in live code but I am running into an issue with testing. How do I disable the caching for testing?

I am currently using

```
#caching.py
from dogpile.cache import make_region

region = make_region().configure(
    'dogpile.cache.redis',
    expiration_time = 3600,
    arguments = {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'port': 6379
    }
)

#db.py
from .caching import region

@region.cache_on_arguments()
def fetch_from_db(item):
    return some_database.lookup(item)
```

How do I swap out the caching or disable it for unittests?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, I didn't have enough points for a dogpile.cache tag.

Answer (score 8):

During testing configure dogpile to use a [`NullBackend`](http://dogpilecache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#null-backend), which is an example of the [Null Object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

```
from dogpile.cache import make_region

region = make_region().configure(
    'dogpile.cache.null'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your decorator into an identity function.

I.e.

```
if __debug__:
    def dont_cache():
        def noop(f):
            return f
        return noop
    class Nothing:
        pass
    region = Nothing()
    region.cache_on_arguments = dont_cache
else:
    from .caching import region
```